# Lightning slds Visualforce

Tags: lightning, navigation

I need a navigation in salesforce classic and I use the lightning components to create a navigation. So far so good, but how can I use the icons, if I add the code below to my visualforce the icons doesn't appear. How can I show the icon?

Is it possible to change the color of the section header?

The code below is the sample from the designsystem.

```
<div class="demo-only" style="width: 320px;">
<nav class="slds-nav-vertical" aria-label="Sub page">
<div class="slds-nav-vertical__section">
<h2 id="entity-header" class="slds-nav-vertical__title slds-text-title_caps">Reports</h2>
<ul>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item slds-is-active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header" aria-current="page">Recent</a></li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header">Created by Me</a></li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header">Private Reports</a></li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header">Public Reports</a></li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="entity-header">All Reports</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="slds-nav-vertical__section">
<h2 id="folder-header" class="slds-nav-vertical__title slds-text-title_caps">Folders</h2>
<ul>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="folder-header">
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-open_folder slds-line-height_reset" title="Description of icon when needed">
<svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_x-small slds-m-right_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#open_folder" />
</svg>
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Folder</span>
</span>Created by Me</a>
</li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="folder-header">
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-open_folder slds-line-height_reset" title="Description of icon when needed">
<svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-icon_x-small slds-m-right_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#open_folder" />
</svg>
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Folder</span>
</span>Shared with Me</a>
</li>
<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-describedby="folder-header">All Reports</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Using SLDS Icons in Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_icons.htm) says:

> The Lightning Design System (SLDS) includes PNG and SVG (both
>   individual and spritemap) versions of our action, custom, doctype,
>   standard, and utility icons.
>
> To use SVG spritemap icons in your Visualforce page, add the
>   attributes `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` to
>   the `<html>` tag.

Alternately, use the png format instead of svg format if you don't want to mess around with adding XML namespaces to your code.

Comment: Ok, but this codesnippet is already in the code? Or where I have to insert this code?

Comment: @peXeq As far as I can tell, it must be on the HTML tag itself for it to work correctly in all browsers. You might want to look at the documentation.